# Getting (referer : None) when scraping a Website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I was recently trying to scrape a website using Scrapy. I used the Base_url and a Start_request method to get the links from a CSV file(it is about 60K) but when I start my spider, it skips some of the links like below:
2020-05-21 10:03:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-3151766>](https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-3151766%3E) (referer: None)
and works for the rest. I tried to scrape only some of the specific links and the work just fine if I di do them one by one.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import os
from ..items import PricedataItem
from ..Product_ID import read_csv

base_url = 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-{}'


class EvaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Eva'

    # start_urls = ['https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-3151766']

    def start_requests(self):
        for ID in read_csv():
            yield scrapy.Request(base_url.format(ID))

    def parse(self, response):
        items = PricedataItem()

        product_name = response.css('.c-product__title::text').extract()
        group = response.css('.c-breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) span::text').extract()
        main_category = response.css('.c-breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) span::text').extract()
        sub_category = response.css('.c-breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) span::text').extract()
        price = response.css('.c-product__seller-price-pure::text')
        brand = response.css('.c-product__title-container--brand-link:nth-child(1)::text')
        product_id = response.css('div.container article::attr(data-product-id)').extract()

        items['Price'] = price
        if items['Price']:
            items['Price'] = price.extract()
        else:
            items['Price'] = 'null'
        items['ProductName'] = product_name
        items['Group'] = group
        items['MainCategory'] = main_category
        items['SubCategory'] = sub_category
        items['Brand'] = brand
        if items['Brand']:
            items['Brand'] = brand.extract()
        else:
            items['Brand'] = "No Brand"
        items['ProductID'] = product_id

        yield items
```